# How to get TightVNC to capture keystrokes

Tags: tightvnc

TightVNC works fantastically for me, with low latency, high resolution, etc. But when trying to do everyday work, I can't manage to use keyboard shortcuts like Alt-Tab because they get capture by Windows instead of TightVNC. Is there any way to use my remote computer 'naturally' , with the same keyboard shortcuts I would otherwise use, etc.? Unfortunately, using TightVNC's GUI 'Ctrl', 'Alt', etc. buttons is not a realistic solution for everyday use.

Comment: Have you considered UltraVNC?  http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-viewer.html *"When SCROLL-LOCK is activated, all keycombinations (except CTRL+ALT+DEL) are directly sentto the remote computer:"* which includes Alt-Tab.  More are detailed  in the bottom half of that page